# How to remove border of Material UI's DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

Here is the datepicker component

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      padding: 0, 
      "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
        padding: 0,
        paddingLeft: 10
      },
      "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
        padding: 15,
        paddingLeft: 0
      }
    }
  }
});

function InlineDatePickerDemo(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        className={classes.root}
        autoOk
        variant="inline"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        label="With keyboard"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
       InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
        onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date)}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default InlineDatePickerDemo;
```

From [codeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/64336432how-to-change-padding-of-material-uis-datepicker-forked-z5ees?file=/src/DatePickerDemo.tsx:0-1123) can anyone tell how to remove border from all sides ?
Although I managed to know that .MuiInput-underline:before style class is responsible for border width but dont know where to put that class in makeStyles.

Comment: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#customization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to edit a bit the `KeyboardDatePicker` element:

1. Remove `inputVariant="outlined"`
2. Add

```
InputProps={{
  disableUnderline: true
}}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/64336432how-to-change-padding-of-material-uis-datepicker-forked-s4m0s?file=/src/DatePickerDemo.tsx)

Comment: This improved my ui quality and I got my intended answer.

Comment: @AnkitaRay cool! Could you mark the answer as accepted then?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

With MUI Datepicker version 6 and above we need to use `slotProps`. Adding sample code below:

```
<DatePicker
    label="Date of Birth"
    value={account.dob}
    onChange={inputsHandler}
    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    slotProps={{ textField: { variant: 'standard', } }}  {/** set variant here */}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      padding: 0,
      "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
        padding: 0,
        paddingLeft: 10,
      },
      "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
        padding: 15,
        paddingLeft: 0
      },
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        border: 'none'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

in MUI you can add variant="standard" to TextField :

```
 renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="standard" {...params} />}
```

completely :

```
 <DesktopDatePicker
                inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                className="mt-0 w-100"
                required={required}
                margin="normal"
                id="date-picker-dialog"
                label={label}
                format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                value={value}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="standard" {...params} />}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just necessary to remove `inputVariant="outlined"` props. So your code becomes:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
    className={classes.root}
    autoOk
    variant="inline"
    label="With keyboard"
    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    value={selectedDate}
    InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
    onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date)}
  />
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/64336432how-to-change-padding-of-material-uis-datepicker-forked-92onl?file=/src/DatePickerDemo.tsx) your code modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont even want that bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CSS . add the below code into your CSS, it really worked for me. Thanks

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border: none ! important ;
}
```